# How to check if a element is the first or last of the current element-node (element parent)

Tags: jquery

i have a simple question and by look around if find many answeare near at my question but not exactly for my situation.

So, i have this html

```
<div class="daddy">
  <div class="child-kevin"></div>
  <div class="child-marvin"></div>
  <div class="child-charlotte"></div>
</div>
```

Now i'm one a point in my script where i have the

element of child-marvin.

How can i check if "child-marvin" is the first and last one in the element "daddy"?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please post your script where you want to check if "child-marvin" is the first and last one in the element "daddy"?

Comment: Use `if ($('.child-marvin').is(':first-child')){...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @Mohammad

$('.child-marvin').is(':first-child')

$('.child-marvin').is(':last-child')